# PowerShell Sending output to Email

Tags: powershell

I have working PS script for getting the info about my cubes processing date and size etc.. so now i am trying to send out mail passing the output to variable..so far no luck any one can help me here.... appreciate for help.

```
enter code here

try{
$asServer="server";
$loadInfo = 
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName(“Microsoft.AnalysisServices”)
$server = New-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server
$server.connect($asServer)
if ($server.name -eq $null) {
Write-Output (“Server ‘{0}’ not found” -f $asServer)
break
}
$sum=0
foreach ($d in $server.Databases)
{ 
Write-output( “Database: {0}; Status: {1}; Size: {2}MB;Last Schema Update: 
{3};Last Cube Processed:{4} ” -f $d.Name, $d.State, 
($d.EstimatedSize/1024/1024).ToString(“#,##0”),$d.LastSchemaUpdate, 
$d.LastProcessed ) 
#$output = Write-output( “Database: {0}; Status: {1}; Size: {2}MB;Last 
Schema Update:{3};Last Cube Processed:{4} ” -f $database.Name, 
$server.State, 
($server.EstimatedSize/1024/1024).ToString(“#,##0”),
$server.LastSchemaUpdate, $server.LastProcessed )
#$sum=$sum+$d.EstimatedSize/1024/1024
$cube ="find the cube processing 
information.-$($server.Name),-$($server.LastProcessed)"
} 
-ErrorAction Stop
 }
catch{
$ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
#Write-Host "Query executed"
Send-MailMessage -From 'alert@mail.com' -To 'user1@mail.com' -Subject 
'Cube Refresh Status' -body $output -SmtpServer 'smtp.mailserver.com'
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What is the error message you get?

Comment: Please **indent** your code properly. This way, it's hard on the eyes and difficult to see mistakes.

Comment: Hello Alex, i did not have error but when i run the send-mailmessage in the for each loop it returning mail for every cube database... but i wanted to send single mail about all the cubes information. i have tried to write the output to variable but that did not worked out.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are trying to send the email inside the "catch" claws so if your script runs without any problems the part with the Send-MailMessage will never run.

I would also suggest you to add a write-host line with some info just to know that you reach the right line, for example:

```
Write-Host "Reached Here"
```

Then you know for sure that this line was reached and you can debug from there.
You can also use the debugging option of PowerShell ISE to run line by line.

Or to just run your script line-by-line using F8

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved -

```
new code changes here --

$output=Write-output( “Database: {0};Size: {2}MB;Last Schema Update:{3};Last Cube 
Processed:{4} ” -f $d.Name, $d.State,($d.EstimatedSize/1024/1024).ToString(“#,##0”), 
$d.LastSchemaUpdate, $d.LastProcessed ) |Out-File **c:\temp\output.txt -Append**
```

and added variable for outfile

```
$out_file="C:\temp\output.txt"

$body = Get-Content $out_file | Out-String
```

and changed the -body parameter as below.
    -body $body
and had to use the $body variable.

Sure there are few more enhancements to the code can be done.